# Simple Voting phpmyadmin mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running an apache2 webserver and want to run a database off of it using phpmyadmin. I am making an android app that needs to connec to make http requests. The app is a simple app where there are 2 buttons and the user can click on the buttons as many times as they want to vote on each person. I was thinking of creating one table with 2 columns in it with the name as "person1" and "perosn2" but according to my research, that won't work. Could anybody give me a simple run through of how i would get this to work. i hve confused myself.

Comment: At this point your asking us to do your work/homework. please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to write better questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want 2 tables something like this.

**People:**

id | name

**Votes:**

id | person_id | timestamp

When someone votes for someone, create a new record on the votes table using the correct person ID. The id could be stored on the android device if it doesn't need to be dynamic.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. would the person id be necessary?

Comment: The reason for doing person_id is to keep your data small. So each vote stores 2 ids and a timestamp. Rather than a text string. You could store just one table with 

`id | name | timestamp (optional)`

But it's bad practice to repeat the same data, if you find your repeating data you should put it in another table.

Also another reason to keep the persons name in another table is so it could change. If you had 1000 votes on a table with the name stored, you would need to update all of those rows in the DB. This way it's stored in 1 row in another table.

Comment: If this answers your question, can you check my question as the correct answer?